# Sum of variable outside a unbounded structure

Tags: sum, xquery

I am looking for a help where I need to check for a element from a unbounded structure and then later need to put a count for same variable outside of a unbounded structure.

Like in below given sample structure, where ConsumptionPerRecord is a unbounded structure and can contain N repetition, where in this structure we have NotConsumed element which contains a value.

I need to look through the structure and do a count of all NotConsumed available in ConsumptionPerRecord structure and display a sum value in TotalNotConsumed field.

This structure is getting drafted at run (a resume of existing XQuery transformation) time and I am not quite sure on how to manipulate this variable alone.

```
  <ns0:Response xmlns:ns0="http://testV4">
<ns0:ReferenceData>Dummy Client reference</ns0:ReferenceData>
<ns0:DataDetails>
  <ns0:Status>Not Available</ns0:Status>
    <ns0:ConsumptionPerRecord>
         <ns0:SizeType>A</ns0:SizeType>
         <ns0:Count>2</ns0:Count>
         <ns0:Consumption>0</ns0:Consumption>
         <ns0:NotConsumed>5</ns0:NotConsumed>
    </ns0:ConsumptionPerRecord>
    <ns0:ConsumptionPerRecord>
         <ns0:SizeType>A</ns0:SizeType>
         <ns0:Count>2</ns0:Count>
         <ns0:Consumption>0</ns0:Consumption>
         <ns0:NotConsumed>2</ns0:NotConsumed>
  </ns0:ConsumptionPerRecord>
  <ns0:ConsumptionPerRecord>
         <ns0:SizeType>A</ns0:SizeType>
         <ns0:Count>2</ns0:Count>
         <ns0:Consumption>0</ns0:Consumption>
         <ns0:NotConsumed>1</ns0:NotConsumed>
  </ns0:ConsumptionPerRecord>
 <ns0:TotalNotConsumed>8</ns0:TotalNotConsumed>
</ns0:DataDetails>
 <ns0:Shipment>
  <ns0:ShipmentId>ABCD12345</ns0:ShipmentId>
 </ns0:Shipment>
 <ns0:Message>Success</ns0:Message>
  <ns0:StatusCode>1000</ns0:StatusCode>
    </ns0:Response>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry but i m not sure if you are trying to update the response record or create a new record? Also if there already is a XQUery running you should include that in your question.

The following fiddle will calculate the sum you are looking for based on your input.

Don't iterate with a flower and you can simply call `sum`

```
declare namespace ns0 = "http://testV4";

 let $response := ns0:Response
 let $consumption := $response//ns0:ConsumptionPerRecord
 let $not := $consumption/ns0:NotConsumed

 return
    <ns0:TotalNotConsumed>{sum($not)}</ns0:TotalNotConsumed>
```

http://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWcDMec/1

Comment: Sorry for not being clear on question but above given structure I am getting after a simple request- response transformation( a simple data mapping) but challenge I am having in drafting a value for TotalNotConsumed which is a sum on NotConsumed from ConsumptionPerRecord unbounded structure.